# Go makes heap allocation doing type assertion on string

Tags: go

```
func Benchmark_maybeString(b *testing.B) {
    str := "foobar"

    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = maybeString(str)
    }
}

func maybeString(val any) string {
    switch val.(type) {
    case string:
        return val.(string)
    default:
        return ""
    }
}
```

```
Benchmark_maybeString        0.3118 ns/op          0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

However, changing the `default` case, which doesn't even run in the benchmark, to something more complicated suddenly makes the function allocate:

```
func maybeString(val any) string {
    switch val.(type) {
    case string:
        return val.(string)
    default:
        return fmt.Sprintf("not a string: %T", val)
    }
}
```

```
Benchmark_maybeString           18.65 ns/op       16 B/op          1 allocs/op
```

Why? If it's because the string is escaping to heap, does it mean Go can allocate strings on the stack? How about the following version, which i assume should be in the heap from the very beginning but still allocates:

```
data := map[string]string{
    "foobar": time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339),
}
maybeString(data["foobar"])
```

## Figured so far

1. Changing `str := "foobar"` to `const str = "foobar"` or `var str any = "foobar"` makes 0 allocations in both version. Why? Are somehow strings in Go not always allocated equally?
2. The allocating version calls `runtime.convTstring()` before performing the type assertion `CMPL`. But what does the `go:string."foobar"(SB)` syntax mean? [image]

Comment: When you pass the string to `fmt.Printf` it needs to escape to the heap, therefor it shows up as an allocation. Has nothing to do with type assertions.

Answer (score 3):

The allocation is due to `fmt.Sprintf` taking an interface, so the compiler transforms your `string` into an interface to invoke the function (the `runtime.convTstring` you see), but apparently the compiler is dumb here.

1, The allocation is only needed in the default case, it should not be put before type switching, pushing the allocation into where it is needed will surely remove the allocation.

2, The other option is to hoist the allocation out of the loop, which also helps eliminate the allocation inside the loop. This requires the compiler to know that the pointer in the `iface` struct points to a constant, though.

3, The type switch should be folded, I believe [this change](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/486895) will fix this.

For your questions:

1, Change `str := "foobar"` to `const str = "foobar"` allows the compiler to eliminate the allocation because `str` lives outside the stack and is constant, so the allocation can be done at compile time. And changing to `var str any = "foobar"` hoist the allocation outside of the loop, so there is no allocation inside.

2, `go:string."foobar"(SB)` is the address of the buffer contains the char array "foobar", this line of code loads that address into `rax`, and the following one loads the length into `rbx`. This is because `runtime.convTstring` takes a `string`, which consists of a pointer and an int. The Go calling convention put the first 2 primitive arguments in `rax` and `rbx`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

It boils down the fact that Go can allocate things on the stack if escape analysis at compile time determines it doesn't escape the current goroutine's stack. Introducing code that passes string to `fmt.Sprintf()` args makes it decide the string escapes stack.

A version where the string is already outside stack don't allocate. For example:

```
const str = "foobar"
```

```
var str any = "foobar"
```

```
str := map[string]any{
    "foobar": fmt.Sprintf("%v", time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)),
}["foobar"]
```